# yarn installed 2 versions of jquery. Why, and how can I fix it except directly editing yarn.lock?

Tags: jquery, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

```
yarn add foo
yarn add jquery-form
yarn add jquery@2.2.4
```

`foo` declares dependency `"jquery@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0"`, `jquery-form` declares `jquery@>=1.7.2`

In my opinion I should have `jquery@2.2.4`, but here is my `yarn.lock`

```
jquery@2.2.4, "jquery@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0":
  version "2.2.4"
  resolved "..."

jquery@>=1.11.1, jquery@>=1.7.2:
  version "3.3.1"
  resolved ".."
```

So, in productuion `jquery-form` got `3.3.1` while `foo` got `2.2.4`.
I now have 2 different jqueries which is not good:)

I fixed it with

```
jquery@2.2.4, jquery@>=1.11.1, jquery@>=1.7.2, "jquery@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0":
  version "2.2.4"
  resolved "..."
```

Everything is resloved on `2.2.4` now.  But I `yarn.lock` is not something you should edit manually.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 8):

TL;TR: `"resolutions": { "jquery": "2.2.4"  }` in `package.json`

Original `npm` (before 3.0) used to install all dependencies in tree mode (some kind of side-by-side). In old times if module `A` depended on `jquery-1` and module `B` depended on `jquery-2` `npm` did the following

```
node_modules/A/node_modules/jquery-1
node_modules/B/node_modules/jquery-2
```

Which is OK for server, but not for client. So they used `bower` which produced **flat** dependencies: only one version for each library. Its was developer's duty to resolve all conflicts.

Nowadays `bower` is deprecated and both `npm` (3+) and `yarn` resolve dependencies in flat mode id they can, but if `yarn` can't do that -- you have two versions of `jquery` again.

One can force yarn to use flat mode: `yarn --flat`. It will ask you about every single conflict:

```
info Unable to find a suitable version for "jquery", please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
 1) "jquery@2.2.4, jquery@>=2.2.0" which resolved to "2.2.4"
 2) "jquery@>=1.7.2, jquery@>=1.11.1, jquery@>=1.7.2" which resolved to "3.3.1"
```

I do not know why can't it be resolved to `2.2.4` (we should ask `semver` author I believe)), but click `2` here and `yarn` will save your choice to `package.json` (not `yarn.lock`!).

```
"author": "Foo",
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"resolutions": {
  "jquery": "2.2.4"
}
```

Problem is solved. It is good to use `yarn --flat` for all client-side code.